# How can I pass parameter to Macro in batch Pipeline of Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have seen about Macros and dynamic pipelines [Building Dynamic Pipelines in Cloud Data Fusion Using Macros] (https://www.qwiklabs.com/focuses/12371?parent=catalog), however this solves some scenarios in development or test environment.
Nevertheless, how I can to pass the values in the macro label in productive environment? I mean, if I have a macro `${bq.dataset}` on BigQuery sink and I need set a value in runtime with the consideration that this data fusion pipeline is triggered from google composer o any other scheduled mechanism.
In other case, maybe I need to set a date value for query import in a database source:
[Import query within macro value for dynamic ingestion to cloud storage or bigquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu94M.png)

In this case, my values for macro can be:

```
{"bq.dataset": "myTable"}
```

I need to implement a productive pipeline with parameter in runtime (without human intervention).

I hope you can help me to find de best way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be solved by using preferences. Please let us know if that solves your usecase

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the issue is to change the parameter values on  runtime, if i define values on system preferences olways will have the same value. for example, a date that can be differente for the Imput Query [database node] in every execution, one way are data fusion macros and argument setter node, but I need to set a new calculated external value in each execution, is it possible?

Comment: Like you mentioned argument setter is one option. Another one is to use runtime arguments: https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/1188036746/Runtime+Arguments